# UDP communication between JavaScript and Python

Tags: javascript, python, udp, multiplayer

I am planning to make a multiplayer game with a JavaScript based Client UI and Python on the server side. The game will be dynamic, so communication speed is very important - consequently I have decided to use UDP. Does anyone have any tips on implementations I could utilize. What tools would you recommend for this project?

Comment: Please don't make the assumption that UDP is necessarily faster than TCP. Gracefully handling packetloss yourself can be quite tricky, and TCP works very well for many situations requiring low latency...

Comment: You can't use UDP with javascript without some sort of browser plugin

Answer (score 4):

I recommend doing the <strike>dumbest</strike> simplest thing to get your project to work, meaning probably http and Json. Then deal with any performance problems. Otherwise you'll spend much of your project on a hard optimization problem that might not really matter.

Comment: ...where `dumbest` really means smartest!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using SockJS + Tornado for this sort of thing. Easy to get started with, and well supported in modern browsers.